# How do i simultaneously read and modify a large CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file, io

I have a large csv file that i need to iterate over and modify in various ways. It is too big for me to load into memory.

In the below code, what i am trying to do is remove the 4th column from my data.

```
import os
import csv

DIR_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
FILE_NAME = "file-name"
DELIMITER = ";"
POINTER = 0

#Generator function that yields individual rows.
def get_row(csvfile, delimiter):
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=delimiter)
        global POINTER
        POINTER = csvfile.tell() #Initial position before any rows processed
        for row in datareader:
            yield row 
            csvfile.seek(POINTER)
        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csvfile = open(os.path.join(DIR_PATH, FILE_NAME + ".csv"), 'r+')
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = DELIMITER, quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    count = 0
    for row in get_row(csvfile,DELIMITER):
        #Write every entry except row[4] 
    
        csvfile.seek(POINTER)
  
        datawriter.writerow(tuple(row[ii] for ii in range(len(row)) if ii != 4))
        
        POINTER = csvfile.tell()
    

    csvfile.close()
```

My output looks as follows:

Header row gets written fine.

Then it prints the the last few characters of the header row AGAIN but in its own row.

Then the first entry is missing the first character.

Then everything else is fine and behaves as expected.

Looks like this:

```
Header 1; Header 2; Header 3; Header 4; Header 5
4; Header 5
Ata 1; Data 2; Data 3; Data 4; Data 5;
Data 1; Data 2; Data 3; Data 4; Data 5;
Data 1; Data 2; Data 3; Data 4; Data 5;
...
```

I don't see why it's going wrong. I am explicitly marking where to read and write.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use temp file to write the data without overwriting the original file. And at the end of script you can move the temp file as original file.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that your `fh.tell` and `fh.seek` doesn't throw you into an infinite loop

Comment: @Ritesh The tempfile and main file existing at the same time would take up too much space. Device would run out of memory (storage space).

Comment: A CSV file is a text file. Rewriting over a text file is a very dangerous operation. It only makes sense when new lines ar shorter that initial ones (ok here), and requires keeping 2 file pointers, one for reading and one for writing and consistently adding a seek between read and write operations. It is much simpler are more robust to write to a temp file, and rename at the end.

Comment: You should have enough disk space for a second copy of the file?  Memory should not be an issue as this could be processed one line at a time. Read one line, process it, write it to temp. If this is too slow, you would read say 1000 lines into memory, process them and write 1000 lines. Rewriting a file in place should not be attempted.